# Why doesn't this formula work in summation of cubes? but works in summation of squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

$$
\sum^{n}_{k=1} k^3 = ({n^2(n+1)^2})/4
$$

right?

say for example k not equal to 1, why doesn't this work? I subtracted the summation of k-1?
$$
\sum^{n}_{k!=1} k^3 = ({n^2(n+1)^2 - (k-1)^2k^2})/4
$$

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Do you understand that $k$ is not a constant here, so it has no meaning outside the $\sum$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is here. What exactly are you trying to show?

Comment: say for example k starts at a number other than 1, like 3

Comment: Presumably, he means $$\sum_{k\neq 1}^n$$, which is meaningless

Comment: @ThomasAndrews meaningless how?

Comment: So you mean $$\sum_{k=j}^n k^3 = \frac{{n^2(n+1)^2 - (j-1)^2j^2}}4$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yeah exactly!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews because I got the formula by subtracting the summation of j, I thought it would work but then I checked my answer using a calculator. So how do you derive it if it starts with j?

Comment: Do you have an example $n,j$ for which it does not work? Works for me.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews nevermind, double checked it again. Although I thought you said it was meaningless?

Comment: Your notation was meaningless - I had to ask several questions to figure out what you meant by your notation. $$\sum_{k\neq 1}^n$$ is not a valid mathematical formula (and there was no interpreation of it that gave me what you meanted to ask, since you meant $k=j$ or $k>j-1$ or some such.)

Comment: Also, there is no way for $\sum_k$ to end up being a function of $k$ because $\sum_k$ is an expression that means as $k$ varies, so the right side can't have $k$ in it - there is no one value of $k$ to put on the right side. That was why I added the variable $j$ as the "starting point."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring your title, if you are asking for $$\sum^{n}_{k=j} k^3 $$  (so starting at $j$ instead of $1$) you can write $$\sum^{n}_{k=j} k^3 = \sum^{n}_{k=1} k^3 -\sum^{j-1}_{k=1} k^3=({n^2(n+1)^2})/4-(j^2(j-1)^2)/4$$

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer the question as best I can. For any sum, the following identity holds, where $n > m > a$:

$$\sum_{k=a}^{n}{f(k)}=\sum_{k=a}^{m}{f(k)}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}{f(k)}$$

From this, we can note and conclude, via substitutions:

$$\sum_{k=a}^{n}{f(k - b)}=\sum_{k=a-b}^{n-b}{f(k)}$$
So:
$$\sum_{k=b}^{n}{f(k)}=\sum_{k=a}^{n}{f(k)}-\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}{f(k)}$$